# concat series onto dataframe with column name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rename, series

I want to add a Series (`s`) to a Pandas DataFrame (`df`) as a new column. The series has more values than there are rows in the dataframe, so I am using the `concat` method along axis 1.

`df = pd.concat((df, s), axis=1)`

This works, but the new column of the dataframe representing the series is given an arbitrary numerical column name, and I would like this column to have a specific name instead.

*Is there a way to add a series to a dataframe, when the series is longer than the rows of the dataframe, and with a specified column name in the resulting dataframe?*

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can try [`Series.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html):

```
df = pd.concat((df, s.rename('col')), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 14):

One option is simply to specify the name when creating the series:

`example_scores = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'], name='example_scores')`

Using the name attribute when creating the series is all I needed.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
df = pd.concat((df, s.rename('CoolColumnName')), axis=1)
```